# Align text with labels, both in different minipages

Tags: color, minipage, cv, alignment, setspace

I am trying to put everything lined up correctly but I can not figure how to center the right text to the left labels

I also want the exactly the same interline spacing which I can't get as you can see on the attached picture but I will probably open another question for this other issue.

**Here's a minimal working example :**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
 \setstretch{1.7}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth} 
        \vspace{-\baselineskip} % Required for vertically aligning minipages
    \begin{flushright}
        %\baselineskip=1.5\baselineskip %another way of tweaking interline space
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{Programming}\\
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{Tools} \\
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{Languages} \\
         \color{white}\colorbox{black}{Libraries} \\
    \end{flushright} 
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill %Whitespace between
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth} 
        \vspace{-\baselineskip} % Required for vertically aligning minipages
        \begin{flushleft}
            %\baselineskip=1.5\baselineskip %another way of tweaking interline space
            \enskip \color{black}{C#, Java}\\
            \enskip \color{black}{Git, SVN} \\
            \enskip \color{black}{English, blabla..} \\
            \enskip \color{black}{JavaFX, Gson, blablaaa..} \\
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

**Output** :

[image: output]

(It is a resume as you can guess..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lot easier with a simple `tabular` (or `tabularx` if you expect to need linebreaks in the second column):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
 \setstretch{1.7}
    {\noindent\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\color{white}\bfseries}rl}
    \colorbox{black}{Programming} & C\#, Java \\
    \colorbox{black}{Tools}       &  Git, SVN \\
    \colorbox{black}{Languages}   &  English, blabla.. \\
    \colorbox{black}{Libraries}   & JavaFX, Gson, blablaaa.. 
    \end{tabular}}
    
    {\noindent\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\color{white}\bfseries}rX}
    \colorbox{black}{Programming} & C\#, Java \\
    \colorbox{black}{Tools}       &  Git, SVN \\
    \colorbox{black}{Languages}   &  English, blabla.. \\
    \colorbox{black}{Libraries}   & JavaFX, Gson, blablaaa.. 
    \end{tabularx}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting a `tabular` environment. :-) A suggestion: since white on black is not particularly easy or pleasant to read, consider changing `>{\color{white}}r` to `>{\color{white}\bfseries}r`.

Comment: Thank you both, everytime I come here I feel like I don't know anything haha!

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for your suggestion. Using `\bfseries` definitely increases the readability. I have edited my answer accordingly.